# Drupal Webform Conditional Page Breaks

Tags: drupal-7, formatting, conditional-statements, drupal-webform

We have a semi-complex webform built using Drupal 7 / Webform 7.x-4.15.

We want to move the "Page Breaks" depending on the URL of the current page (we are showing the webform in a block). We are "moving" page breaks by hiding/showing different page breaks using conditionals and hidden "URL" field that is populated with current page URL.

The current page hidden “URL” field is at the top of the form above the first page break.

We can get the first example to work perfect. When we try and get other options to work, we can no longer see fields that are between the page breaks.

Example 1: example.com/page1 (Hide / Show Page Breaks)

- Field 1
- Field 2
- Page Break1 (Show)
- Field 3
- Field 4
- Page Break2 (Show)
- Field 5
- Page Break3 (Hide)
- Field 6
- FINISH

Example 2: example.com/page2 (Hide / Show Page Breaks)

- Field 1
- Field 2
- Page Break1 (Hide)
- Field 3
- Field 4
- Page Break2 (Show)
- Field 5
- Page Break3 (Hide)
- Field 6
- FINISH

Example 3: example.com/page3 (Hide All Page Breaks)

- Field 1
- Field 2
- Page Break 1 (Hide)
- Field 3
- Field 4
- Page Break2 (Hide)
- Field 5
- Page Break 3 (Hide)
- Field 6
- FINISH

How can we get this to work so we can effectively move page breaks between fields depending on URL of current page?

Cheers,

Dane